# Center any element on a sliding horizontal line

Tags: javascript, css

I have a horizontally sliding line of elements within a fixed width, so you have to scroll left an right to see all the elements. See [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3y6s5vx/) and text-only example below.

```
Hi | Hello | How do you do | Fine thanks | Good weather this time of year
```

My question is: How can I *center* any given element horizonally? Eg. Put the horizontal center of element number 3 in the horizontal center of the surrounding div.

If the element can't be centered because it is at the beginning of the line for example, that's OK, then the H-position should simply be 0. It should only be centered as much as it *can* be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like this?  You can use a combination of the following native properties `scrollLeft`, `offsetLeft`, and `offsetWidth`.

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper ul li');

function centerItems(which) {
  var wrapper = items[which].offsetParent;
  wrapper.scrollLeft = 
    (items[which].offsetLeft + items[which].offsetWidth / 2)
      - wrapper.offsetWidth / 2;
}
```

```css
html {
 background: #eee;
}
body {
 width: 320px;
 background: white;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
   overflow-x: scroll;
   position: relative;
}

ul {
   white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #898;
    background: #efe;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello!</p>

<button onclick="centerItems(0)">1</button>
<button onclick="centerItems(1)">2</button>
<button onclick="centerItems(2)">3</button>
<button onclick="centerItems(3)">4</button>
<button onclick="centerItems(4)">5</button>

<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>Short</li>
        <li>Very long line here</li>
        <li>Medium line</li>
        <li>Another one Another one Another one</li>
        <li>Yet another</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<p>Goodbye!</p>
```